# Where can I find API key for a making a free/busy ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a post HTTP request to the free/busy link, but I can't find the API key.

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy?key=??",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
         timeMin: (new Date(2016, 3, 1)).toISOString(),
         timeMax: (new Date(2016, 3, 30)).toISOString()
      }
});
```

I've tried using the client secret key, client id, and browser API key (suggested from first answer). None of these work.

I wonder if it's even possible to request busy free times like this.

Comment: Are you having trouble retrieving data or are you having trouble finding your API key in Google developer administration?

Comment: Without the key, I can't test it. I'm not even sure there is a key.

Comment: http://wpdocs.philderksen.com/google-calendar-events/getting-started/api-key-settings/

Answer (score 2):

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?

1. Make sure your current project is selected
2. Create Credentials > API Key > Browser Key

Then go to https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/calendar/overview?
and Enable the calendar API